# cannot match the string that finishes with one equality or two equality

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this

```
[network-traffic:src_port =
```

and I want to check it it ends with = or ==  or !=

I have a regex like this

```
[^=]*={1}
```

just to start and now when feed it with ssss=== it matches and in the first step I am failing as 3 = is also matching though I need only 1 or 2 equality to be matched

what is the best way to achieve the above?

Comment: Can you show an example of a full string?

Comment: you can tell the regex that the line should end with 1 or 2 equal signs `^[^=]*={1,2}$`

Comment: Changing your quantifier from `{1}` to `{1,2}` will only match one or two equal signs, like so: `^[^=]*={1,2$}`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I used yours here and still matching https://regex101.com/. please try ssss===

Comment: for 1 0r is working but also for 3 equals is working

Comment: @AdiDarachi here is the sample string [network-traffic:src_port =

Comment: @ChrisDoyle just tried again and working can you put some explanation for ^[^=]*={1,2}$ that is the right answer

Comment: it works for me https://regex101.com/r/kE3nWj/1/

Comment: @ChrisDoyle sorry tried again and working can you explain it a bit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following regex `^[^=]*(?:={1,2}|!=)$` it breaks down as follows

```
match the start of the line
match 0 or more chars which are not an =
match 1 or 2 = OR match !=
match the end of the line
```

Comment: I'm not that great at regex, but your regex seems a bit wrong... I think `'[network-traffic:src_port ==!='` should `true`, but yours returns `false`. To be honest, I don't fully understand the questioner's requirement. So, I'm sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: oops i didnt see the != requirement, updated now. I am not sure if `==!=` is valid or not, the OP just said ends in `=` or  `==` or `!=`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```js
function validate(str) {
  return /(?<!.*=)([=!])?=$/.test(str)
}

console.log(validate('[network-traffic:src_port =')); // True
console.log(validate('[network-traffic:src_port ==!=')); // True
console.log(validate('ssss=== it')); // False
console.log(validate('ssss=== it===')); // False
```